# Ошибка Undefined offset: 1 in

Tags: php, mysql

Пытаюсь переписать значения в бд используя массивы, каждый раз ругается на значение индекса $row[t2] в строчке :

```
 $query1='INSERT INTO  days_time SET "'.$str2.'"="'.$row[$t2].'" WHERE id="'.$id2.'" ';
```

Вот полный листинг:

```
$j=1;
$id=2;
$t1=1;
while($j<=7)
{ 

 $str="time_".$id;


 $query='SELECT "'.$str.'" FROM days_time';

 $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

 $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

 $t2=0;
 $id2=1;
 $str2="time_".$t1;
while ($t2<=6)
{ 
  $query1='INSERT INTO  days_time SET "'.$str2.'"="'.$row[$t2].'" WHERE id="'.$id2.'" ';
  mysqli_query($con,$query1);
  $t2++;
  $id2++;

}

 $id++;
 $j++;
 $t1++;

}
```

Comment: посмотрите содержимое массива. там нет элемента под номером 1 что бы это ни значило. А в `insert` не бывает фразы `where`, не понятно, что вы под ней подразумевали. И подставлять значения в текст запроса вообще нельзя, следует использовать привязываемые переменные http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php  И кстати любую вставку в БД (или обновление) записей на основе значений из других таблиц БД можно вообще выполнить одним запросом и ни писать ни строчки кода на php

Comment: и еще судя по коду я подозреваю что у вас в таблице много колонок типа time_1, time_2 и т.п. это неправильная структура БД, нарушена 1я нормальная форма, стоит пересмотреть структуру. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0